# Datos duplicados dentro de rango de fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito saber que folios estan duplicados dentro de un rango de fecha, de un departamento en especifico, tenog esta consulta pero me saltan algunos errores:

```
select n.numero, n.nombre from Empleado as n where n.Fecha = '2022-05-29 00:00:00.000' between n.Fecha = '2022-05-30 00:00:00.000'
 and n.ID_departamento = '123'
 group by numero,nombre having COUNT(*)>1
```

> incorrect sintax near between
> incorrect sintax near '*'. Especting
> '(' or SELECT

Ademas como puedo eliminar esos duplicados?

Comment: esta mal escrito el between.. es n.fecha between unafecha and otrafecha...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como comenta @gbianchi, la sintaxis del `between` es incorrecta.

```
select n.numero, n.nombre from Empleado as n 
where n.Fecha between '2022-05-29' and '2022-05-30'
and n.ID_departamento = '123'
group by numero,nombre 
having COUNT(*)>1
```